# Section display issue in I.fopath form

Tags: forms, infopath

I have an infopath form which users use to fill details and approver approves. The approver section in form is displayed to only those whose ID is present in hidden field. This was working fine before but now even approvers could not see approver section. Recently I added an user in hidden field after which it worked fine for sometime. Now all approvers could not see the approver section itself.

Comment: Adding to above, viewing approver section for usernames in hidden field is based on rule in infopath form

Comment: Feel free to edit directly the question with new information, so everything will be in the same place. Furthermore, show us what you've tried so far (source code, a proof of concept, results), otherwise it's very hard you're getting any help

Answer (score 0):

Things to check:

- if you are using multiple views in the form, make sure you are updating them as needed and not only updating one view and forgetting the others.
- if you remove the lase user you added tonthe hidden input, does the issue go away? How are you inserting users in hidden input? Seperating them by some character?
- try to display the id of the current user in the form and display the hidden input and make sure the id's really match or there is any difference